# Move cell data in every other row from column H to I and replace text in B and C

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I'm new to macro's and need to the following on 1,000+ line sheet:

I have a sheet and and i need to duplicate every other row and then modified the new rows.

to duplicate the additional row i run this macro:

```
    Sub CopyRows()
Dim LR As Long
Dim i As Long

LR = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    For i = LR To 2 Step -1
        Rows(i).Copy
        Range(Rows(i + 1), Rows(i + 1)).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next i

End Sub
```

There are two additional operations I need to do on every other row after the header row.

Operation 1:
In columns B and C I need to replace the text with "data for B" and "Data for C" the text is static for each replacement.

Operation 2:
I need to cut the data in Column H and paste it in column I.

Any help in doing this Macro would be appreciated.

This is in Excel 2016

My final solution thanks to @MortenAnthonsen his solution gave me what I needed to work the following out:

```
Sub myMaker()
Dim LR As Long
Dim i As Long

LR = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    For i = LR To 2 Step -1
        Rows(i).Copy
        Range(Rows(i + 1), Rows(i + 1)).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next i

For i = 3 To Cells(2, 2).End(xlDown).Row Step 2
    Cells(i, 2).Value = "B Data"
    Cells(i, 3).Value = "C Data"

    Range("H" & i).Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("I" & i).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Add an illustration or the file

Comment: I'm sorry but I have to tell you that this is not a free code writing service. Can you show the code you already have so we can tell whats wrong with it?

Comment: If you've looking to perform an activity while skipping rows, you will most likely need to use For... Next statements, specifically stating the Step, e.g. For i = 1 to LastRow Step 2.  Once you look into the For statement, you should be better to write your macro, and if you have questions with your specific coding, you can always post and SO can help review your code if it does not run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
Sub operations()
Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To Cells(2, 2).End(xlDown).Row Step 2
    Cells(i, 2).Value = "data for B"
    Cells(i, 3).Value = "Data for C"
Next i

Range(Range("H2"), Range("H2").End(xlDown)).Cut Destination:= _
Range(Range("H2"), Range("H2").End(xlDown)).Offset(0, 1)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, it didn't exactly what I wanted but it gave me the approach I needed to get it working, i have edited the question with my solution.